# How to create a new json using regex which is a subset of other json using javascript?

Tags: javascript, json

For example, suppose my json looks  like this

```
{
  "post_new_visits": "Repeat",
  "post_new1_week": "Thursday",
  "post_new2_appt": "Weekday",
  "post_new3_site": "12:50AM",
  "post_new4_channel": "5.0",
  "pre_new2_appt": "Weekday",
  "pre_new3_site": "12:50AM",
  "pre_new4_channel": "5.0"
}
```

I want a new JSON, which should only have "post*" key values, something like below, the output should be like this.

```
{
  "post_new_visits": "Repeat",
  "post_new1_week": "Thursday",
  "post_new2_appt": "Weekday",
  "post_new3_site": "12:50AM",
  "post_new4_channel": "5.0",
}
```

is there any way I can achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may go like that:

```js
const src = {"post_new_visits":"Repeat","post_new1_week":"Thursday","post_new2_appt":"Weekday","post_new3_site":"12:50AM","post_new4_channel":"5.0","pre_new2_appt":"Weekday","pre_new3_site":"12:50AM","pre_new4_channel":"5.0","inter_something":"someValue", "super_something":"some other value"},

      result = Object
        .keys(src)
        .reduce((r,k) => {
          const prefixes = ['post', 'inter', 'super']
          if(prefixes.some(prefix => k.startsWith(prefix)))
            r[k] = src[k]
          return r
        }, {})
          
console.log(result)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height:100%;}
```

Comment: if i want to include more keys, for example 'post' and 'xxx'?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a for-in loop:

```
let o1 = {
  "post_new_visits": "Repeat",
  "post_new1_week": "Thursday",
  "post_new2_appt": "Weekday",
  "post_new3_site": "12:50AM",
  "post_new4_channel": "5.0",
  "pre_new2_appt": "Weekday",
  "pre_new3_site": "12:50AM",
  "pre_new4_channel": "5.0"
};

let res = {};
for (const key in o1) {
  if (key.indexOf('post') === 0) {
    res[key] = o1[key];
  }
}
console.info(res);
```

Result:

```
{
  post_new_visits: 'Repeat',
  post_new1_week: 'Thursday',
  post_new2_appt: 'Weekday',
  post_new3_site: '12:50AM',
  post_new4_channel: '5.0'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

May use [JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse), it receives two parameters which the second parameter `reviver` is a transformation function. We can compute the value by the `reviver` function. If the reviver function returns undefined the property is deleted from the JSON object.

```js
const src = '{"post_new_visits":"Repeat","post_new1_week":"Thursday","post_new2_appt":"Weekday","post_new3_site":"12:50AM","post_new4_channel":"5.0","pre_new2_appt":"Weekday","pre_new3_site":"12:50AM","pre_new4_channel":"5.0","inter_something":"someValue", "super_something":"some other value"}';

const res = JSON.parse(src, (k, v) => {
    // we walk to top level when k equals to empty, so we return v directly.
    if (k === "") {
        return v;
    }
    // delete non-starting with "post" property
    if (!k.startsWith("post")) {
        return undefined;
    }
    return v;
});
console.log(res);
```